# Simple sql question help

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select

I have a table with usernames and categories and I have the query:

```
select * from articles where username='333' or username='222' and category='movies'
```

I want this to return just the records from the users '333' and '222' which are from the 'movies' category, but this returns all the articles from those users from all the categories.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM articles
    WHERE (username='333' OR username='222')
        AND category='movies'
```

Comment: @K Ivonov - you're answer says 4 min. ago, Chris' says 5 min ago on mine

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from articles where (username='333' or username='222') and category='movies'
```

Answer (score 3):

It might help to use the IN keyword instead of AND/OR.

```
select *
from articles
where username in ('333','222') and category='movies'
```

IN allows you to specify a list of values.

Also, if you want to **MIX** AND/OR, make sure you bracket them.  If you don't bracket them, the **precedence** in most major RDBMS is AND before OR (bracket around the ANDS).

```
select *
from articles
where (username = '333' or username = '222') and category='movies'
```

As you can see from here [(Operator Precedence (TSQL 2005)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), `AND` comes in at number 7 whereas `OR` comes in at number 8.

Answer (score 2):

Probably your lack of parenthesis. If you are more explicit, something like:

```
select * from articles where (username='333' or username='222') and category='movies'
```

then you should be ok.

There's also an `IN` keyword, so you can do:

```
select * from articles where username in ('333', '222') and category='movies'
```

Answer (score 2):

operator precedure. You might want to read the manual. AND binds tighter (has higher precedence than) 'OR', hence your query is being parsed as

```
select *
from articles
where username = '333' or ( username = '222' and category = 'movies' )
```

You need to use parentheses to explicitly specify the order of operations you want:

```
select *
from foo
where ( user = 'a' or user  = 'b' )
  and category = 'c'
```

alternatively, use `in`:

```
select *
from foo
where user in ('a','b')
  and category = 'c'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting it to be parsed:

```
select * from articles where (username='333' or username='222') and category='movies'
```

But instead it is parsed:

```
select * from articles where username='333' or (username='222' and category='movies')
```

Put parentheses in and it will do the right thing.